# How to insert into table using link tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have `ArtistProduct` model. User enters the product details, user can view the entered details in modal window by clicking the preview link before saving the details.

I'm trying to save the data using AJAX by passing all the details like params when it is validated, but it not saving the database.

In view I'm calling AJAX:

```
var theVal=id+'/'+artist_id+'/'+name+'/'+desc+'/'+price+'/'+story+'/'+artist_name+'/'+dimension+'/'+material+'/'+contact
var theURL = '/add_temp/' + theVal;
$.ajax({
  url: theURL
});
```

In controller I'm handling it like so:

```
def add_temp
  @pro_id=ArtistProduct.where("id=?",params[:id])
  if @pro_id.nil?
    @artistprod = ArtistProduct.new(:artist_id=>58, :product_name=>params[:name], :description=>params[:desc], :product_price=>params[:price], :product_story=>params[:story],:artist_name=>params[:artist_name], :dimensions=>params[:dimension],:material=>params[:material],:contact_number=>params[:contact])
    @artistprod.save
  end 
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your reply.

Now am getting Routing error.

In my Router I have like:

```
match 'add_temp/:id/:artist_id/:name/:desc/:price/:story/:artist_name/:dimension/:material/:contact'=> 'artist_products#add_temp'
```

---

**UPDATE**

## Routing Error

404 Not Found

```
No route matches [POST] "/add_temp/P58018/58/Prod/swsx/50/sfdf/null/null/0"
```

**UPDATE**

### Ya i identified it and corrected it but still also values are not saving into the database. Please help me

In Controller i am doing like so:

```
    def add_temp

      if !(ArtistProduct.where("id=?",params[:id]).exists?) 
      @artistprod=ArtistProduct.new(:id=>params[:id],:artist_id=>58, :product_name=>params[:name], :description=>params[:desc], :product_price=>params[:price], :product_story=>params[:story],:artist_name=>params[:artist_name], :dimensions=>params[:dimension],:material=>params[:material],:contact_number=>params[:contact])
      @artistprod.save
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to @artistprod.addproduct }
         format.js
       end
     end 
    end
```

Hi dbkooper, Thanks for your answer. I tried answer given by u but am getting Routing error
In view am calling like:

```
        var theURL = '/artist_products/'+id+'/add_temp?artist_id='+artist_id+'product_name='+name+'description='+desc+'product_price='+price+'product_story='+story+'artist_name='+artist_name+'dimensions='+dimension+'material='+material+'contact_number='+contact;
```

Comment: You need to provide the exact error that is shown in the server logs.

Comment: You have 9 params you are passing in, but the route expects you to pass in 10 params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem I see is that your `$.ajax` call is missing some options.  By default, `$.ajax` defaults to a `GET` request if no type is specified.

You should change it to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: theURL,
  success: function (json) {
    // handle your success here
  },
  error: function (response) {
    // handle your errors here
  }
});
```

This way, you specify that it will be a `POST` request and you also have callback methods for handling `success` and `error`

Comment: Thank you every much. Now values are saving in the database successfully.

Comment: Glad to help! Please click the checkmark next to my answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes should be

```
resources artist_products do 
    member do 
         post 'add_temp' 
     end
end
```

use rake :routes to get  the correct routes 
most probab it will be "artist_products/:id/add_temp"

For ajax request it will be you can send the val param's using ? to the url
like

```
var theURL = '/artist_products/'+id+'/add_temp?artist_id='+artist_id+'so on..'; 
$.ajax({   url: theURL });
```

Inside your controller 
you can access params as usual